# Desktop diff tool with all files together

Tags: windows, diff

Is there a GUI diff tool for Desktop Windows that can compare folders, and show *each different file with the differences in the same screen, below each other*?

Tools like Meld etc. give just a list first, with markers which files are different at all. Then I can open the files one by one to check the actual differences:

[image: Meld] [image: Meld]
<sup>Screenshots of *Meld* (taken from HowToForge.com)</sup>

What I'd like is something like the Bitbucket diff as desktop application, a second file would be shown right below the first one:

[image: Bitbucket]
<sup>Bitbucket (taken from Atlassian Wiki)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is what you are after, but WinMerge is very good at comparing folders and files.

Comment: But it can't do what the question asked...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Bitbucket diff. However, I've used Beyond Compare (http://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php) for years for comparing/merging files and folders in my professional life.

Comment: This too - apparently it can't fulfil the requirement, or I'm too stupid to find it.